# ¿Cómo usar font-awesome con Framework7?

Tags: phonegap, framework7, font-awesome

Buenas tardes!
Estoy haciendo una app con phonegap, utilizando Framework7.
La cosa es que quiero usar font awesome con ello. 
Primero probé usando los framework7 icons, los descargué y coloqué los archivos css en la carpeta css y las fuentes en fonts.

Si en mi vista pongo:

```
<i class="f7-icons size-22">home</i>
```

Se me muestra el icono de la casita. =)

Ahora hago el mismo proceso con font-awesome, y pongo un:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

Y no se visualiza nada.
Obviamente he puesto la ruta correcta al archivo css...

También he probado poniendo una cdn externa y nada...

He buscado pero no he encontrado nada. En la documentación solo habla de font awesome con vue, pero no es mi caso...

Comment: el problema que tienes es que font-awesome no te reconoce los iconos con las clases?

Comment: Me ha funcionado ya. He vuelto a bajampee font awesome e instalarlo en las carpetas y ya me funciona. No tengo ni idea de qué ha pasado... =(

Comment: Aa ok interesante, suele suceder.